# vb.net - Can't acces custom Form property/method from another Form

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net form with this code:

```
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class frmTransAlqPago
    Private dt As DataTable
    Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Private BaseDatos As String

    Private cProp As cPropietario
    Private cAlqu As cAlquiler
    Private cClie As cCliente
    Private cPrda As cPropiedad

#Region "Propiedades"
    Private mvarIDAlqu As Long
    Private mvarIDClie As Long
    Private mvarIDProp As Long
    Private mvarIDPrda As Long
    Private mvarFecDeu As Date
    Public WriteOnly Property pIDAlqu() As Long
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            mvarIDAlqu = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public WriteOnly Property pIDClie() As Long
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            mvarIDClie = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public WriteOnly Property pIDProp() As Long
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            mvarIDProp = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public WriteOnly Property pIDPrda() As Date
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            mvarpIDPrda = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public WriteOnly Property pFecDeu() As Long
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            mvarFecDeu = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
    Private Sub mObtieneObjetos()

        cClie.mClienteGet(CType(txtIDClie.Text, Integer))
        cAlqu.mAlqPagoGet(CType(txtIDAlqu.Text, Integer))
        cPrda.mPropGet(CType(txtIDPrda.Text, Integer))
        cProp.mGetPropietario(CType(txtIDProp.Text, Integer))

    End Sub
...
...
...
```

On another Form I have:

```
    Private Sub btnImprimir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImprimir.Click
        Dim frm As Form = New frmTransAlqPago
        frm.Controls.Item("txtIDAlqu").Text = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(4).Value, Integer)
        frm.Controls.Item("txtIDPrda").Text = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(5).Value, Integer)
        frm.Controls.Item("txtIDClie").Text = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(6).Value, Integer)
        frm.Controls.Item("txtIDProp").Text = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(7).Value, Integer)
        frm.Controls.Item("txtAlqRec").Text = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(0).Value, Integer)

        frm.pfecdeu = CType(dgvVarios.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(0).Value, Integer)
```

The last instruction is given me an error. In fact autocomplete function doesn't recognize frm.pFecDeu
So how can I acces custom property/method from one Form into another one? I'm writing code in Visaul Studio 2015

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is `Dim frm As Form = New frmTransAlqPago`.

And my solution is `Dim frm As frmTransAlqPago = New frmTransAlqPago`.

Comment: Oh! nice catch! Thank!

Comment: You could shorten that to `Dim frm As New frmTransAlqPago`.  Then you are only typing the type once...